Example of semi algebraic subset over a real closed field
I am trying to find interesting example of semi algebraic subset over a real closed field other than those we have by considering $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I tried to construct an example involving matrices. For this I first consider the commutative ring $(M,.,+)$ of $n$ by $n$ matrix defined with enterwise addition and multiplication. But I realized that going further with this, I will not get a field.
I think that there is no reasonable way to defined a field of matrices.
My initial aim was to prove that the cone of symmetric positive semi definite matrix is a semi algebraic subset of the space of symmetric matrix. However the set of symmetric matrix is not a real closed field which is the framework needed to speak about semi algebraicity.
I am wondering where I am wrong please.
Thank you a lot !

The cone of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices is a semialgebraic subset of the space of symmetric matrices (which can be seen as some $\mathbb{R}^n$ treating the entries of the matrix as coordinates). Indeed, a symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite iff all its symmetric minors are nonnegative.
